# Maximal Modular Ideals in a Commutative Banach Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, modules

Let $ X $ be a commutative Banach algebra, $ x \in X $, and let $ \lambda $ be a nonzero complex number.  Let:

$$ J = \left \{ \lambda^{-1}xy - y : y \in X \right \} $$

I am trying to show that $ J $ is a maximal modular ideal of $ X $.  It is easy to show that $ J $ is an ideal of $ X $ and that $ J $ is modular with modular unit $ \lambda^{-1}x $. I am having difficulties showing that $ J $ is maximal though.  I am trying to prove this by contradiction.

Suppose that $ J $ is not a maximal ideal of $ X $.  Let $ M $ be a maximal ideal of $ X $ containing $ J $ and let $ m \in M \setminus J $.  Then $ m \neq \lambda^{-1}xy - y $ for any $ y \in X $.  At this point I am stuck in finding a contradiction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that one approach may be showing that the ideal has codimension 1. If $J$ actually is maximal modular, then $X/J\cong \mathbb C$, and $\phi(x)=\lambda$. So you could show that each element $z\in X$ could be written $z=\alpha x+\lambda^{-1}xy-y$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb C$, $y\in X$.